# How I can add all wikipedia images to my docx file?

Tags: python, wikipedia, python-docx

I am working with the wikipedia api and I want to put all the photos on the page to the docx document. At the moment I can put only one image on the document, but this is not good. And some pages from wikipedia doesn`t give me any photo and when I search on the internet I can see there are some photos on the site .Here is my code:

```
import wikipedia
import re
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.shared import Mm
import requests
import io
from docx.shared import Inches

name = input("Introdu numele tau: ")
wikipedia.set_lang("ro")
hs = input("La ce liceu esti?\n")
cls = input("In ce clasa esti?\n")
date = input("Pe ce data trebuie facut proiectul?\n")
title = input("Despre ce vrei sa fie proiectul tau?\n")
while True:
    try:
        wiki = wikipedia.page(title)
        break
    except:
        print("Nume proiect invalid")
        title = input("Introdu alt nume de proiect: \n")
text = wiki.content
text = re.sub(r'==', '', text)
text = re.sub(r'=', '', text)
text = re.sub(r'\n', '\n    ', text)
split = text.split('Vezi și', 1)
text = split[0]
print(text)

document = Document()

section = document.sections[0]
section.page_height = Mm(297)
section.page_width = Mm(210)
section.left_margin = Mm(25.4)
section.right_margin = Mm(25.4)
section.top_margin = Mm(25.4)
section.bottom_margin = Mm(25.4)
section.header_distance = Mm(12.7)
section.footer_distance = Mm(12.7)

style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = Pt(12)

url = wiki.images[1]
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
image = io.BytesIO(response.content)
try:
    document.add_picture(image, width=Inches(1.5))
except:
    pass


paragraph = document.add_paragraph(date)
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
paragraph = document.add_paragraph(name)
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('Clasa '+cls)
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
paragraph = document.add_paragraph(hs)
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
paragraph = document.add_heading(title, 0)
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('    ' + text)
paragraph.style = document.styles['Normal']
paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT


document.save(title + ".docx")
input()
```

I think the fault is here:

```
url = wiki.images[1]
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
image = io.BytesIO(response.content)
try:
    document.add_picture(image, width=Inches(1.5))
except:
    pass
```

because is display on the docx document only one image

Comment: I think you're going to run out of disk space as this will be a very large .docx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you explore *loops* and *functions* in Python. A loop gives you the ability to execute some code zero or more times and a function allows you to group a chunk of code together and access it by name. In fancier language this is called *abstraction*.

A loop for this Wikipedia purpose would be something like:

```
for image in wiki.images:
    document.add_picture(image, ...)
```

Then if `wiki.images` was empty, no pictures would be added. If it had 5 images, all five would be added.

A function might be like:

```
def add_wiki_image(document, image_url):
    response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
    image = io.BytesIO(response.content)
    document.add_picture(image, width=Inches(1.5)
```

And could be called like:

```
for image_url in wiki.images:
    add_wiki_image(document, image_url)
```

Having `add_wiki_image()` as a function allows that code to be referenced concisely ("called") from wherever you need it, and the details that go into implementing that image-add operation are neatly *encapsulated* in the function definition.

Comment: When I add your code I get this error docx.image.exceptions.UnrecognizedImageError

Comment: Does it work for some images but not others? `python-docx` cannot accept all image types, for example SVG is popular on Wikipedia but `python-docx` cannot process it. Try putting a `try-except` block around the `.add_picture()` call and `pass` on that error and see if you get at least some of the images you're expecting.